# Replacing parts of the string

Tags: python, string, bash, sed, split

Actually my question is quite simple:
I have a string like: `101222_1_1_ab`;
I hope to change it into: `101222_1_ab_1`

What bash commands should I use? and what to do in python?
THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest mechanism I can think of is to use `awk(1)`:

```
$ echo 101222_1_1_ab | awk -F_ '{print $1 "_" $2 "_" $4 "_" $3;}'
101222_1_ab_1
```

The `-F_` asks `awk(1)` to split fields apart on underscores.

**Update** Glenn Jackman recommends the following, far more legible, version:

```
awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '{print $1, $2, $4, $3}'
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the underscores inside the awk body, you could use: `awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '{print $1, $2, $4, $3}'`

Comment: @glenn, yes, that's _far_ better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 101222_1_1_ab | sed -r -e 's/(.*_.*_)(.*)_(.*)/\1\3_\2/'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
# echo "101222_1_1_ab" | sed -re 's/(_[^_]+)(_.*)$/\2\1/'
101222_1_ab_1
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I would use `awk` for this.

```
$ echo 101222_1_1_ab | awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "_"} {print $1, $2, $4, $3}' 
101222_1_ab_1
```

But since you ask:

> and what to do in python?

```
>>> s = '101222_1_1_ab'
>>> s.split('_')
['101222', '1', '1', 'ab']
>>> l = s.split('_')
>>> l[0], l[1], l[3], l[2]
('101222', '1', 'ab', '1')
>>> '_'.join((l[0], l[1], l[3], l[2]))
'101222_1_ab_1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sed, this splits at the underscores and rearranges:

```
echo 101222_1_1_ab | sed 's/\(.*_.*\)_\(.*\)_\(.*\)/\1_\3_\2/'
```

**Edit** As @dmitry.malikov points out, the `-r` option can make it much more readable:

```
echo 101222_1_1_ab | sed -r 's/(.*_.*)_(.*)_(.*)/\1_\3_\2/'
```

Comment: It looks better without so much escapes `echo 101222_1_1_ab | sed -r -e 's/(.*_.*_)(.*)_(.*)/\1\3_\2/'`

Comment: By the way, your example returns  101222_1_1_ab

Comment: @dmitry.malikov:  In a previous edit, I cut-n-pasted extra single quotes in it, which made it incorrect.  I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Just with bash:

```
word=101222_1_1_ab
new=$(
  IFS=_
  parts=($word)
  tmp=${parts[2]}; parts[2]=${parts[3]}; parts[3]=$tmp
  printf "%s" "${parts[*]}"
)
echo $new # => 101222_1_ab_1
```

Comment: That could be shortened to   
`#!/bin/bash`   
`word='101222_1_1_ab' IFS='_' parts=( $word )`   
`echo "${parts[0]}_${parts[1]}_${parts[3]}_${parts[2]}"`

Answer (score 1):

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
word='101222_1_1_ab' IFS='_' parts=( $word )
echo "${parts[0]}_${parts[1]}_${parts[3]}_${parts[2]}"
```

(wanted to put this in reply to glenn jackman)